# Get current app's build version - Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to display the app's build version in my settings page.

So how can i get the `versionCode` and `versionName` from `AndroidManifest.xml` file programmatically.

Or

Is there any way to get the build version programmatically in `xamarin.forms`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**For version name:**

```
Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionName
```

**For version code:**

```
Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionCode
```

Answer (score 32):

With a Dependency service:

For iOS:

```
using Foundation;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Screen_iOS))]

namespace XXX.iOS
{
    public class Screen_iOS : IScreen
    {

        public string Version
        {
            get
            {
                NSObject ver = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"];
                return ver.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For Android:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ScreenAndroid))]

namespace XXX.Droid
{
    class ScreenAndroid : Java.Lang.Object, IScreen
    {

        public string Version
        {
            get
            {
                var context = Forms.Context;
                return context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0).VersionName;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
interface IScreen
{
    string Version { get; }
}
```

Comment: Note that it only worked for me when I used the full namespace in the registration attribute, which would be in this case : 
assembly: Dependency(typeof(XXX.Droid.ScreenAndroid ))]

Comment: Forms.Context is obsolete.  Use Android.App.Application.Context instead.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353986/xamarin-forms-forms-context-is-obsolete

Answer (score 19):

In [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/essentials/app-information) you can use the following:

```cs
Version version = AppInfo.Version;
```

From there you can get the build version.

If you really just want the build number you can also use the shortcut:

```cs
string buildNumber = AppInfo.BuildString;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Xamarin.Android` you could always try:

```
public double GetAppVersion()
{
   var info = AppContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(AppContext.PackageName, 0);
   return info.VersionCode;
}
```

and then you will need to use [dependency injection](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to call this method from your `Xamarin.Forms` project.